# Responsive Mobile Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that applies a class to the html element and also detects if a drop down has been clicked below the width of 900px.

When I resize the browser from desktop view to below 900px I find occasionally that the dropdown class "active-hit" doesn't get applied - meaning that the menu won't open. Any ideas why this might be? I have to reload the page to make it work in mobile view.

```
// Add Mobile View Class to HTML ELEMENT below 900px
(function($) {
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html');
    $dropdown = $('.dropdown-nav > a');

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 900) {

      $dropdown.on('click', function(e){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active-hit');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      return $html.addClass('mobile-view');

    } else {
      $html.removeClass('mobile-view');
      $dropdown.parent().removeClass('active-hit');
    }

}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Of course you have to reload the page because manually changing the size of your window doesn't trigger resize function. Everything should work just fine when it will be opened on real mobile device with width under 900px, so no worries about it

Comment: I would prefer a trigger to be on window resize too. In testing it is annoying to have to reload the page each time.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, window resize will not trigger your function, but if You want to do so in testing purposes then you can try to use this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
});
```

And here is working [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t4xkyz19/) for you